# External WebService Call From ASP.NET JQuery Ajax

Tags: asp.net, web-services, jquery

I Am Calling a webservice that is hosted in the server. The JQuery Ajax Call is as Follows

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx/GetCountries',
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonp: 'jsonp',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (res) {                    
                $("#success").append(JSON.parse(res));
            },
            error: function (error) {
                $("#success").append(error);
            }
        });
```

It's Supposed to return all countries. But I Am Getting An Error from Chrome Cansole. Saying That

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/xml: "http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx/GetCountries?jsonp=jQuery172030371484998613596_1344382564214&_=1344382675101". jquery.min.js:4
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Any help would be greatly appreciable

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The server is returning Javascript with `content-type:text/plain` in HTTP headers.
Reconfigure it to return with `content-type:application/x-javascript` to fix it.

Comment: How can i do that ? can you give me an example ?

Comment: And That is problem with External Web Service

Comment: Sadly there is hardly anything that you can do to fix it. Try reporting it as a bug to webservicex.